# How to play the audio of a SoundCloud song via URL input

Tags: java, url, soundcloud, minecraft, playsound

I am coding a Minecraft plugin, (Just a modification to the game Minecraft but used on a Minecraft server, not a client modification)

and I want to create something that when a player inputs

"/playsong"

along with a SoundCloud URL, it will find that URL and loop it.

(being able to play a soundcloud playlist will be much appreciated)

All the other work will be done by me. (checking if the URL is null, testing if the player sends /playsong along with a valid URL, etc.)

Adding comments with // telling me what certain bits of code do will be much appreciated.

Thank you for reading.

~Matthew274

Answer (score 0):

This generally is not possible.  Minecraft does not have any way to play an arbitrary song that requires downloading from a remote server.  There are a few ways you could still do this, but it isn't simple.

One technique would be to take the song and attempt to convert it to a series of notes for use with `/playsound` (or noteblocks).  That isn't easy nor will it give a perfect result, but it *is* hypothetically doable (though I don't know any of the details).

The other technique would be to create a resource pack, send it to the client, and then have them play the song.  That as well is nontrivial, but still doable.  The general procedure would be:

- Find and download the song from soundcloud (I don't know soundcloud's API for this, but I assume they have one).
- If necessary, convert the song into a `.ogg` file from `.mp3`.  There's probably also a library for this.
- Create a resource pack with that sound (and the appropriate sound index) and temporarily make it for download on your server.
- Send a [Resource Pack Send](http://wiki.vg/Protocol#Resource_Pack_Send) packet linking to that resource pack.
- Wait for the client to respond with [Resource Pack Status](http://wiki.vg/Protocol#Resource_Pack_Status) of "accepted".
- Play the song using the [Named Sound Effect](http://wiki.vg/Protocol#Named_Sound_Effect) packet (or `/playsound`).

This process is not simple, but if you do somethings like keeping a collection of songs in the playlist and sending multiple songs in the resource pack, you *should* be able to implement it.  You'll need [ProtocolLib](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/protocollib/) to send custom packets.

I'm sorry I can't give code for this, but it's a complicated task that would require several parts, none of which I know the *full* details on.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for answering me. It sucks I can't do what I was planning to do.

Comment: What I have come up with, is that a player can download songs into their resource pack, in a new folder called "songs" Then maybe in-game they can do "/playsong radioactive" and it will look for a file in "songs" called "radioactive" If it finds one, it will begin playing the song to the player. If the file "radioactive" is not found, it will send the player a message saying: "The file "radioactive" cannot be found." I hope this one will work!

Comment: @Matthew274 Yea, that should work.  You might need to also create a [custom sound index](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Sounds.json) in the resource pack.